# why the retrived data from json action display as undefined?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone here look at the outputs console.log()  and structure of the table it is right? I think the error is in one of them.
I am trying to get the required data from the database,i'm using console.log() both data in the loadData() function and val in the $.each() and when i click btn1 or btnAllUser it show the required  data in console as javascript object but the result appears undefined in the table fields as apear in the image at the end.I need your help,please.
the following is my controller,View,ajax script:

```
 public JsonResult GetDonatorsWithParameter(int? StateId, string CityName, string blt)
{

    ViewBag.StateId = new SelectList(db.states, "StateId", "StateName");
    ViewBag.CityName = new SelectList(db.cities, "CityId", "CityName");



    return this.Json(new
    {
        result = (from a in db.Donors
                  where (a.StateId == StateId && a.CityName == CityName && a.bloodType == blt)
                  select new { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name, adress =( a.state.StateName+"-"+ a.CityName), PhoneNumber = a.PhoneNumber, bloodType = a.bloodType,Email=a.Email, conn = a.conn, Tconn = a.Tconn }).ToList()
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

the view is :

```
 @{
ViewBag.Title = "GetDonators";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

}

```
 <div class="container" id="con">
<br />
     <div class="form-group row">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
         الدولة: @Html.DropDownList("StateId", (SelectList)ViewBag.StateId, "اختر الدولة", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control mx-2 col-md-2", id = "State" })
         المدينة:@Html.DropDownList("CityName", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-2", id = "city" })
         فصيلة الدم:@Html.DropDownList("blt", new SelectList(new[] { "+A", "-A", "+B", "-B", "+AB", "-AB", "+O", "-O" }), "اختر فصيلة الدم", new { @class = "form-control col-md-2 mr-md-3", id = "bt" })
         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info col-md-1 mr-1" id="btn1" />
         <input type="submit" value=" بحث" class="btn btn-info col-md-1" id="btnAllUser" />

     </div>
</div>



<div id="UpdatePanel">

</div>
```

this my jQuery script:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/jscript">
$(function () {
    $('#State').change(function () {
        $.getJSON('/Donators/Citylist/' + $('#State').val(), function (obj) {
            var items = '<option>اختر المدينة</option>';
            $.each(obj, function (i, city) {
                items += "<option value='" + city.Value + "'>" + city.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $('#city').html(items);
        });
    });

    // This is for Get All Data
    $("#btnAllUser").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetAllDonators", "DonorOnlines")",
            data: "",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            loadData(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
        }
    });

});

// this will use for Get Data based on parameter
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetDonatorsWithParameter", "DonorOnlines")",
        data: {
            StateId: $('#State').val(),
            CityName: $('#city').val(),
            blt: $('#bt').val()
        },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        loadData(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Failed! Please try again.");
    }
});
});

    function loadData(data) {
        
    
     // Here we will format & load/show data
    var tab = $('<table class="table"></table>');
    var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
    thead.append('<th>User ID</th>');
    thead.append('<th>User name</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Address</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Phone</th>');
    thead.append('<th>bloodType</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Email</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Connection way</th>');
    thead.append('<th>time</th>');
    console.log(thead);

    tab.append(thead);
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
        // Append database data here
        var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Id + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Name + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.adress + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.PhoneNumber + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.bloodType + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Email + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.conn + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Tconn + '</td>');
               console.log(val);
               console.log(trow);
        tab.append(trow);
       
    });
    console.log(tab);
    $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
    $("#UpdatePanel").html(tab);
};


});
</script>
```

The output of console.log(data) is

```
result: Array(9)
0: {Id: 4, Name: "علي عبدالله", adress: "اليمن-22", PhoneNumber: "714885965", bloodType: "B-", …}
1: {Id: 5, Name: "هيثم صلاح محمد", adress: "اليمن-24", PhoneNumber: "735699885", bloodType: "+A", …}
2: {Id: 7, Name: "علي قاسم محمد", adress: "اليمن-24", PhoneNumber: "775636545", bloodType: "A+", …}
3: {Id: 8, Name: "hossam", adress: "اليمن-21", PhoneNumber: "775696855", bloodType: "A-", …}
4: {Id: 9, Name: "ali ahmed ali", adress: "اليمن-21", PhoneNumber: "774455661", bloodType: "O+", …}
5: {Id: 10, Name: "salem saleh", adress: "اليمن-21", PhoneNumber: "774488996", bloodType: "+A", …}
6: {Id: 12, Name: "salah ali", adress: "اليمن-21", PhoneNumber: "715489693", bloodType: "+A", …}
7: {Id: 13, Name: "hospital", adress: "اليمن-22", PhoneNumber: "714693145", bloodType: "+A", …}
8: {Id: 14, Name: "salwa", adress: "اليمن-تعز", PhoneNumber: "714569965", bloodType: "-A", …}
```

[image: when i am click btnAllUser]

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it works well.
Check it, maybe you added something else in your code. What exactly console.log(val) return in loadData ?

```js
var test = [
{Id: 4, Name: "علي عبدالله", adress: "اليمن-22", PhoneNumber: "714885965", bloodType: "B-", Email: "test", conn: "conn", Tconn: "123"},
{Id: 4, Name: "علي عبدالله", adress: "اليمن-22", PhoneNumber: "714885965", bloodType: "B-", Email: "test", conn: "conn", Tconn: "123"},
{Id: 4, Name: "علي عبدالله", adress: "اليمن-22", PhoneNumber: "714885965", bloodType: "B-", Email: "test", conn: "conn", Tconn: "123"},
{Id: 4, Name: "علي عبدالله", adress: "اليمن-22", PhoneNumber: "714885965", bloodType: "B-", Email: "test", conn: "conn", Tconn: "123"}];

loadData(test);

function loadData(data) {
     // Here we will format & load/show data
    var tab = $('<table class="table"></table>');
    var thead = $('<thead></thead>');
    thead.append('<th>User ID</th>');
    thead.append('<th>User name</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Address</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Phone</th>');
    thead.append('<th>bloodType</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Email</th>');
    thead.append('<th>Connection way</th>');
    thead.append('<th>time</th>');

    tab.append(thead);
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            console.log(i);
        console.log(val);

        // Append database data here
        var trow = $('<tr></tr>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Id + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Name + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.adress + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.PhoneNumber + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.bloodType + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Email + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.conn + '</td>');
        trow.append('<td>' + val.Tconn + '</td>');
        tab.append(trow);
       
    });
    $("tr:odd", tab).css('background-color', '#C4C4C4');
    $("#UpdatePanel").html(tab);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="con">
<br />
     <div class="form-group row">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;
         الدولة: @Html.DropDownList("StateId", (SelectList)ViewBag.StateId, "اختر الدولة", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control mx-2 col-md-2", id = "State" })
         المدينة:@Html.DropDownList("CityName", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-2", id = "city" })
         فصيلة الدم:@Html.DropDownList("blt", new SelectList(new[] { "+A", "-A", "+B", "-B", "+AB", "-AB", "+O", "-O" }), "اختر فصيلة الدم", new { @class = "form-control col-md-2 mr-md-3", id = "bt" })
         <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-info col-md-1 mr-1" id="btn1" />
         <input type="submit" value=" بحث" class="btn btn-info col-md-1" id="btnAllUser" />

     </div>
</div>



<div id="UpdatePanel">

</div>
```

Comment: the json action return data as array of object and i'm edit my json action